# My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS System thinks it's a laptop. How do I fix this?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, power-management

I set up an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server OS to use as a media server.  It is uses desktop hardware with a mobile processor (Intel i5-6600T).  Until recently it has worked fine.  But I recently installed Gnome on it to make management a little easier and it started goingg into sleep mode after several minutes of inactivity.
When I went to Settings -> Power with the intent of disabling Automatic Suspend, and I noticed that it seems to think it's a laptop because of the mobile processor.  Instead of displaying the normal desktop power settings, it shows Battery with a bar showing it 100% charged and it doesn't show the buttons for Automatic Suspend.
I know I can just hit any key on the keyboard to resume functioning, but this system lives in my basement and I xRDP to it usually.

I did manage to find a command that prevented the OS from executing an Automated Suspend, so it is not sleeping now.  That command was:

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

and it is working fine.  But the Power control panel still shows the system as having a battery (like a laptop) and it still doesn't show the Automated Suspend control button.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to correct this?

Comment: Please specify exactly what desktop environment you installed. That will allow identification of the power settings.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information, [edit] your question and add all information there. It might help to mention *what* command you found.

Comment: There seems to be zero evidence to the claim that "Ubuntu thinks it's a laptop". Is there, in fact, any evidence to provide, and if yes, will you provide it? As is, there seems to be nothing to fix.

Comment: I have added the command I used to stop the OS from going into Automated Suspend by editing my original post.   
And, in response to the question about evidence for the claim that "Ubuntu thinks it's a laptop" I can only respond that no other Ubuntu desktop installation I have seen has the Power control panel displaying the state of battery charge or lacks the Automated Suspend switch.  Does yours?   So I assumed that if the OS thinks the system is being powered by a battery, it must think it is a laptop.  Most desktops use AC power.

Comment: Do you have an uninterrupted power supply ([UPS](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-ups)) in between the wall power outlet and your computer?

Comment: Yes, the system is connected to an uninterruptable power supply.

Comment: The UPS is basically a battery. This is why the power control panel shows the system as having a battery (like a laptop).

Answer (score 2):

The comments posted by user68186 offer the answer to my question.  Connecting the system to a UPS and installing the UPS software in Ubuntu is why the power system preference shows a battery charge level meter and no longer shows the Automated Suspend preference setting.
The question is now answered.